# How to load markup with coordinates instead of edit mode?

Tags: javascript, python, json, autodesk-forge

I have rectangle data in a JSON and I would like to create these rectangles (through coordinates instead of user edit mode) in the markup extension. Is that possible? If so, how do I go about doing this?

I've checked the API docs but haven't found any info on this.

Any direction would be very helpful.

Many thanks,
Pau

Comment: Which library/framework are you using? You mention a markup extension but have only tagged your question as python

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. I'm using Forge Viewer. My backend is in Python and all the frontend is in Javascript. Here's the Markup Extension: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/reference/javascript/markupscore/ . I've followed this guide which explains how to use the EnterEditMode https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-autodeskviewingmarkupscore-extension and everything works fine, but my question is if it's possible to draw rectangles without the user interaction (without clicking and dragging) and drawing them with coordinates instead. Thanks!

Comment: [`loadMarkups`](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/reference/javascript/markupscore/#loadmarkups-markupstring-layerid) looks like the function you should be calling. You have to pass it an svg string with your rectangles in it

Comment: Hi there,

Thank you for responding. The problem I face is that my rectangles are dynamic, meaning that they must be drawn in different colours, shapes, etc. depending on an external database. So drawing them beforehand and saving them in an svg is not an option for me. Is there any way to draw them by coordinates?